# Add Estimated Delivery WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm trying to add on product page the estimated delivery.The plugin should has the follow features:
-Delivery time is 4 working days
-Exclude weekends in shipping and delivery
-The cutoff hour is 1:00 pm (13:00)

The code in the function.php is the follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_delivery_estimate');

    function display_delivery_estimate() {
    $now = current_time('timestamp');
    $cutoff_hour = 13;
    $working_days = 4; 
    $delivery_date = "";

    
    $shipping_date = $now;
    
    if (date('H', $now) >= $cutoff_hour) {
        $shipping_date = strtotime('+2 day', $shipping_date); 
    } else {
        $shipping_date = strtotime('+1 day', $shipping_date); 
    }
    $delivery_date=$shipping_date + 2;
    
    if (date('N', $delivery_date) >= 6) {
        $delivery_date = strtotime('+2 days', $delivery_date);
    }
    
    else {
        $delivery_date = strtotime('+4 days', $delivery_date);
    }

    echo '<p>Consegna stimata tra ' . date_i18n('l, j F', $shipping_date) . ' - ' . date_i18n('l, j F', $delivery_date) . '</p>';
}
```

The problem is that the code seem to not works. In the expected days there are still the week days.
How can I fix that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is checking the weekends and skipping to next week.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_delivery_estimate');

function display_delivery_estimate() {
    $now = current_time('timestamp');
    $cutoff_hour = 13;
    $working_days = 4; 
    $delivery_date = "";
    
    $shipping_date = $now;
    
    if (date('H', $now) >= $cutoff_hour) {
        $shipping_date = strtotime('+1 day', $shipping_date); 
    }
    
    $delivery_date = $shipping_date;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $working_days; $i++) {
        $delivery_date = strtotime('+1 day', $delivery_date);

        // Skip weekends (Saturday and Sunday)
        // Here for each weekend day we add +1 day
        while (date('N', $delivery_date) >= 6) {
            $delivery_date = strtotime('+1 day', $delivery_date);
        }
    }

    echo '<p>Consegna stimata tra ' . date_i18n('l, j F', $shipping_date) . ' - ' . date_i18n('l, j F', $delivery_date) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Seem better but the cutoff doesn't works.
I have tried +2 instead of +1 but with this configuration week days, like saturday, are included